# Why use an auto-incrementing primary key when other unique fields exist?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm taking a course called "database systems" and for our class project I have to design a website.

Here's an example of a table I created:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  uid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(60),
  passhash VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(60),
  rdate DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);
```

The professor told me "uid" (user id) was completely useless and unnecessary and I should have used the username as the primary key, since no two users can have the same username.

I told him it was convenient for me use a user id because when I call something like `example.com/viewuser?id=5` I just check the parameter with: `is_numeric($_GET['id'])`... needless to say he was not convinced.

Since I've seen user_id and other similar attributes (thread_id, comment_id, among others) on plenty of tutorials and looking at the database schema of popular software (eg. vbulletin) there must be plenty of other (stronger) reasons.

So my question is: How would you justify the need of a not null auto incrementing id as a primary key vs using another attribute like the username?

Comment: Joe Celko has always spouted the same thing, "You should use meaningful PK's whenever possible."

Comment: are your professor is too much read comic's book than read PHP/MySQL?

Comment: Your professor sounds like a purist.  Relationally, yeah -- if usernames will be unique, user IDs are duplicate data of a sort, as the username and user ID have the same meaning.  But in the real world, they are useful for most if not all of the reasons mentioned below.

Comment: If you don't care very much about your grade, tell your teacher that this is why he is teaching theory instead of working in the industry :p

Comment: Your professor is doing the right thing by pointing out that you should have made username unique and not nullable if it was a requirement that user names should be unique. The uid could be a key as well but unless you are actually using it somewhere then it isn't needed. The more important aspect of the design ought to be to implement the natural key. So I agree with your professor's comment.

Comment: Celko is right - use meaningful PK's **whenever possible**.  There's times you can do that and times you can't.  Given what the OP said it's not possible to tell if this is one of those times or not, nor is it possible to tell if the prof is being obstinately didactic or if there's solid reasoning behind his point.  To the point about thread_id, comment_id, etc - in cases such as these there may not be a "meaningful" key available so an artificial key is necessary - but that doesn't mean artificial keys should always be used.  YMMV.

Comment: I do havea concern about the size of USERNAME. I fyou intend to let people use their email addresses as usernames, then 60 characters is much smaller than the longest possible email address. If you want them to use name like user186909 then 60 seems too long especially if you are going to use it as the natural key you want it to be a small as possible.

Comment: @All: Thanks for the comments!
@HLGEM: What values would you recommend for the size of username and email? Are there any "typical values" people tend to use?

Comment: Blindness. This is why there are some insane websites where they can't change your email and ask you to drop all your coupons, points, and open a new account!

Comment: @SuperDuck, which situation are you commenting?

Comment: @vgv8 : their systems don't allow changing the email address as their systems are built on a similar DB schema, using the email as primary key for users. I know 2 cases, which one is a bigger marketing company's online store. bleh...

Comment: @dportas: I'd be little surprised if 'email' weren't supposed to be unique, too.

Comment: One practical use case for using auto increment keys is what I call the split master design. If you have 2 masters where data is redundantly inserted into you cant to have a slightly different but auto incrementing PK for tables in the 2 masters. For example, one would be 1 and incrementing by 2(odd numbered) and another starting at 2 and incrementing by 2(even numbered). This helps when there may be situations like "split brain" when you can reconcile rows easily.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Auto-incrementing primary keys are useful for several reasons:

- They allow duplicate user names as on Stack Overflow
- They allow the user name (or email address, if that's used to login) to be changed (easily)
- Selects, joins and inserts are faster than varchar primary keys as its much faster to maintain a numeric index
- As you mentioned, validation becomes very simple: `if ((int)$id > 0) { ... }`
- Sanitation of input is trivial: `$id = (int)$_GET['id']`
- There is far less overhead as foreign keys don't have to duplicate potentially large string values

I would say trying to use any piece of string information as a unique identifier for a record is a bad idea when an auto-incrementing numeric key is so readily available.

Systems with unique user names are fine for very small numbers of users, but the Internet has rendered them fundamentally broken. When you consider the sheer number of people named "john" that might have to interact with a website, it's ridiculous to require each of them to use a unique display name. It leads to the awful system we see so frequently with random digits and letters decorating a username.

However, even in a system where you enforced unique usernames, it's still a poor choice for a primary key. Imagine a user with 500 posts: The foreign key in the `posts` table is going to contain the username, duplicated 500 times. The overhead is prohibitive even before you consider that somebody might eventually need to change their username.

Comment: Another point - ORMs hate non-integer keys. Whilst I feel this is a general failing on the part of most ORMs, you do learn to work *with* the tools

Comment: @meagar I hate visiting sites that require me to come up with a unique username for log in. I'd like to abandon the "username" for authentication entirely and move to email address only.

Comment: @Phil Agreed. Everybody on the Internet already *has* a unique identifier, and it's extremely easy to register throw-away addresses for those accounts you don't want to link to your main email address. The single down-side is it introduces a single point of failure; all of your passwords are only as good as your email account's password.

Comment: @meagar I wasn't meaning to use the same password for each service, just use the email address as the "username" credential. Authentication providers (OpenID) are even better IMO

Comment: @Phil I know, I'm saying that once your email is compromised, somebody "owns" all the accounts tied to it. They can visit each site and send password request emails. So, the single point of failure becomes your email account's password.

Comment: @meagar: How do you uniquely identify a user if they don't have a unique name? I don't know many systems where I am expected to identify myself with a number. Usually I have a unique login name.

Comment: Non-unique displayed usernames faciliate social engineering - I wouldn't call that such a great idea.

Comment: @dportas Do Stack Overflow and OpenID ring any bells?

Comment: @meagar: sure, but that's not part of the design being proposed because an auto incrementing ID has nothing to do with an OpenId. My question therefore is what are you suggesting the natural key of this table should be - ie something that identifies an authenticated user in the database?

Comment: @dportas I would use an email address as the login name, and separate it from the displayed username.

Comment: @meager: good, i agree. Email is perhaps a better key than username, but both are better than user_id. The original design is useless and the professor was quite right to say it should be changed.

Comment: @dportas I disagree. The original design is correct (missing `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` constraints aside) in that an auto-incrementing numeric primary key is still the way to go, regardless of whatever other unique pieces of data happen to belong to the record. Especially in this case where so many other tables are likely to have foreign keys pointing to the users table.

Comment: Email "happens" to be unique? Surely the point of the table is that it should accurately represent the identification of a user in the system. For correctness the key on email/username is essential. user_id is very much a secondary consideration because it is merely performance tuning based on your assumptions about those other tables. If you put performance before correctness then you are certainly guilty of "premature optimisation". So I think the point of the Professor's well crafted criticism is to make the OP think first and foremost about accurate design, which has to be a good thing.

Comment: @dportas The point of the table is to serve as a data-store, not to serve as a testament to database normalization. I live in the real world where some major performance problems can be anticipated and prevented with a modicum of foresight. This is not premature optimization; it is common sense and accepted practice virtually everywhere.

Comment: @meagar: in the real world getting accurate data slowly is generally preferable to getting garbage data quickly! The database exists to serve the users with accurate data, not to satisfy the DBA's ego that he made it go as fast as possible while letting data integrity go to hell. On that basis, a key on username or email is far superior to putting a key only on a surrogate user_id (though both options might leave room for improvement). That ought to be a lesson well learned by the OP.

Comment: @dportas I fail to see how adding a guaranteed unique, database-enforced, auto-incrementing unique identifier somehow makes the associated data "garbage". There is a reason every relation database provides this, and virtually every website going takes advantage of it. I would also argue that decoupling referential integrity from potentially variable data is a pretty solid design choice.

Comment: @dportas Adding unique constraints, as I've said *repeatedly*, solves that issue.

Comment: Which is what I said too. So what's to disagree with? I disagreed with your original implication that the original design WITHOUT such a constraint was better than the proposed one WITH it. It isn't - it is clearly worse.

Comment: @meagar and dportas: Thanks for the feedback! Would you agree with this: CREATE TABLE users( uid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, passhash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, rdate DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(uid), UNIQUE (username,email) ); More details: I'll use (email OR username) AND passhash for logins (like twitter, if I recall correctly), username for displaying "by Bob", the uid for viewuser.php?id=5.

Comment: You might want to change: "They allow the user name (or email address, if that's used to login) to be changed" to "They allow the user name (or email address, if that's used to login) to be changed *without cascading updates* ", since you can still change the usernames if they were PKs, but it requires more work.

Answer (score 16):

If the username is the primary key and a user changes his/her username, you will need to update all the tables which have foreign key references to the users table.

Comment: If the user can change his/her/its username then the username is by definition not a candidate primary key.

Comment: The referential action `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is the usual answer to this 'straw man' argument.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: a property of a good key it that the values are stable. Immutable is the ideal but rare changes only is good too.

Comment: @onedaywhen: If you use `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, instead of changing the username in one place, you're changing it in potentially huge numbers of indexed fields.  Meaning a massive performance hit.  And of course, you'll want to do it in a transaction, lest someone see a record that's linked to a username that no longer exists.  In many DBs, this means locking the related rows.  Granted, a user shouldn't be changing their username often.  But if two people do so at once, and they share any records in common (say, intra-site messages), you're looking at potential issues all over the place.

Comment: Surrogate keys do not eliminate problems related to key changes - they make certain problems more manageable but make others more complex. The statement that a changing attribute is not a candidate key is certainly false. Any attribute can change, there are no exceptions - even for surrogates. By definition a candidate key is only required to be unique and irreducible - stability being a useful and important property but not an essential one.

Comment: @cHao: "potentially huge", "massive performance hit"... is this something the OP mentioned? Sounds like you are comfortable using an artificial key to solve an artificial problem.

Comment: @onedaywhen: It's not an "artificial" problem.  I've seen it happen.  In the real world, performance and scalability are *at least* as important as theoretical perfection, and i'd say more so.  You don't lose much, if anything, by using a surrogate key...but you can end up losing quite a bit by not using one.

Comment: @cHao: the opposite seems to be the problem here: the natural key was not enforced and that's what got the OP into trouble. I think the lesson here is to resist blanket solutions ("All tables will benefit from a surrogate key") and premature optimization, instead look for the real life users' real life requirements.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I think there's no lesson here, if that's the lesson.  Any unique/primary key should be enforced, yes -- whether it's the username or user ID, or both.  But i'm also quite comfortable in saying *all* user tables should have a user ID field, and that that field should be the primary key.  "Correct" or not, it's the solution that keeps things sane and scalable.  Some tables would benefit from a "natural" key; user tables are not one of them.

Comment: @cHao: You think it's "sane" to permit duplicate users in a users table? I'll bet those users disagree with you.

Comment: @dportas: No, but i think it's "sane" to allow users to change their names, without locking half the records in the database while they do it.  I didn't say "don't set a unique/not-null constraint on `username`", did i?  Quit acting like there's no possible constraint but the primary key.

Comment: @cHao: So you DO think the table would benefit from a natural key. Therefore there could be a potential downside to the additional User ID. Many if not most DBMSs require indexes to support keys. So the User ID would require the overhead of the server maintaining an additional index. Possibly that's worthwhile, possibly not. Definitely not if you aren't using that column for anything useful. The point is that you ought to weigh up the pros and cons in each case. Like onedaywhen, I prefer a pragmatic, practical approach and I can see no point in dogmatic nonsense like "Always Use A Surrogate".

Comment: @dportas: I think the table would benefit from a unique, not-null constraint on `username`.  I do *not* think there should be 50 kajillion copies of the username floating around (1) that will each take up to 16x the space of an int (as currently specified), (2) that will need to be string-compared every time you want records for a given username (involving much more work than just comparing two ints), and (3) that will all need to be changed if the username changes.  There are quite a few 'cons' to it.  Show me the pros.

Comment: @cHao: I thought I just did that. None of the things you said are implied by what the OP described. I'll just recommend again that anyone considering what keys to implement in this table should evaluate all the options properly and not blindly follow anyone's one-size-fits-all approach. HTH

Comment: @dportas: What you did was use performance as an argument.  Not data integrity, not "correctness".  And the only case where that extra index slows things down any is when creating or deleting a user.  (And you're already updating an index, regardless.  Updating another isn't a big deal, unless you're creating tons of users a minute.)  Everything else is at least as fast, and usually faster, and invariably smaller (unless all your usernames are <4 bytes in length, including the length byte(s).  In which case just about everyone but Joe and Al will *hate* you).

Comment: Unless there's a damn good reason to the contrary (and, yes, passing a DB design course might count as such a reason, if the teacher insists on "correctness" over practicality), *all* user tables should have userID (not null, auto-increment) as a primary key.

Comment: @cHao: There are likely non-peformance related reasons as well of course. I was responding in the same terms that you were just to show that there are alternatives. Is it "at least as fast" to require a join to the user table to retrieve the user name versus doing no join at all? I suspect not... but the only way to tell is to decide based on a particular use case and to ignore anyone who says "always do x".

Comment: @dportas: Considering we both already acknowledge that there's an index for the key, a lookup will be pretty damn fast.  If you only need to know the username, it might *or might not* be a bit faster to have it in the table.  (Having it in the table invariably means having a bigger table.)  But you rarely if ever need to know just the username.

Answer (score 12):

If you have demonstrated to your professor that assigning a unique arbitrary integer to each user is of value to your application then of course he would be wrong to say that it is "completely useless and unnecessary".

However, maybe you missed his point. If he told you that the requirement is that "no two users can have the same username" then you haven't met that requirement.

Sincere thanks for posting your SQL DDL, it is very useful but most don't bother on SO.

Using your table, I can do this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (NULL);
```

Which results in this:

```
SELECT uid, username, passhash, email, rdate 
FROM users;

uid   username   passhash   email   rdate
1     <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>  <NULL>
2     <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>  <NULL>
3     <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>  <NULL>
4     <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>  <NULL>
```

I think is the point your professor was trying to make: without enforcing the natural key on `username` you don't really have any data integrity at all.

If I was the prof, I'd also urge you to remove nullable columns from your design.

Comment: Thanks, I did forget the NOT NULL and UNIQUE constraint. Here's an updated version: CREATE TABLE users( uid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, passhash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, rdate DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(uid), UNIQUE (username,email) );

Comment: `UNIQUE (username, email)` doesn't do what you think it does. You might try testing your own code.

Comment: Yes, that was for @CarlosMarx. Sorry for not making that clearer.

Answer (score 7):

This is typically called a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) and it has many benefits.  One of which is insulating your database relationships from the application data.  More details and the corresponding disadvantages can be found at the wiki link provided above.

Answer (score 4):

Because someone might want to change their username (or any name for that matter).

Answer (score 4):

Your professor is doing the right thing by pointing out that you should have made username unique and not nullable if it was a requirement that user names should be unique. The uid could be a key as well but unless you are actually using it somewhere then it isn't needed. The more important aspect of the design ought to be to implement the natural key. So I agree with your professor's comment.

Comment: I agree with him that it should havea unique constraint, but it is almost always a mistake to use somethign so changeable as a username as PK. Integers are known to be be faster for joins than varchars of this size and updates to potentially millions of FK records when the user name changes can bring your system to a screaming halt. Someone teaching design should know better than to want a natural key for something this changeable.

Comment: @HLGM: I've been on networks and such for almost 3 decades. I can't recall my username ever changing.

Comment: @HLGEM who says usernames are changable?

Comment: A username might be required to change, e.g. if a person changes their name due to marriage for example. It's relatively infrequent though. That key values do sometimes change is just a fact of life, but that doesn't make them less important or useful as keys.

Answer (score 1):

I'll need someone with more database knowledge to back me up on this one, but i believe you get a faster response in foreign key lookup time.

Additionally, you may decide later that you want usernames to change, or that the requirements for usernames may change (maybe a longer string?). Using an ID prevents having to change all foreign keys.

Lets face it, most projects aren't going to expand *that* much, but do you really want to risk the headache 12 months down the road, when you could conform to good programming standards now?

Comment: VARCHAR(4) takes as many bytes as INT; less that that is smaller than INT but that doesn't make it feasible depending on the rules.

Comment: Of course this is varchar (60) so it almost certainly will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, integer search (?id=5) is much way faster and has higher cardinality than string search (?username=bob).
Another example, uid is auto_increment, so you don't have to insert it explicitly but it will auto increment in each insert query.

PS: Your prof is soooo wrong about it :D

Comment: If they are unique then the carnality of the string or number would be the same. If a hash index is used in each case then the seek performance would be about the same in each case. So on the information given there is no basis for saying one is faster than the other. In any case, the point of the question is correctness, not performance. The professor is sooo right!

Comment: @dportas, so are you the professor in question? The professor is so wrong I would fire him if he tried to do something this massively stupid to my databases.

Comment: @HLGEM: I'm not him, but I might consider firing someone who was so stupid as to permit duplicate users in a user table - or at least I would re-educate them by making them define natural keys before surrogates. I expect the prof feels the same way.

Answer (score 0):

we use ID to prevent duplication data and it can make some procces become not complicated (if we want to update or delete data), it more simple if we use ID.

if you dont want to use ID you can use another fields. but dont forget to make them become UNIQUE. it can make your data become preventive from duplication data.

another way outside PRIMARY is UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

I go with all the answers above. I would say an ID is easy to implement and when it comes to indexing, Int is always preferred compared to a varchar. Your professor should know better, why would he say no to Int id is above me!

Answer (score 0):

Because userid is supposed to be unique (cannot be duplicated) & sometimes is index.

Answer (score 0):

And do you want to store your usernames in clear text for any one to steal? I would never consider using a natural key that I might want to encrypt someday (or want to encrypt now).

Comment: If security was a concern then wouldn't you hash the username rather than encrypt it? The hash ought to make a good a good key. If you disagree then what natural key would you use to uniquely identify users? I think we agree that the original design is wrong but what suggestions do you have for the OP?