# is it safe to use non-English characters for the ID part of a datastore key?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I would like to give my users the option of including non-English characters in their usernames.

For simplicity's sake (and to avoid subtle bugs) I would then like to use their username as the id part of the ndb key for their Entity. My question is, is this a safe approach?

I was unable to find information on whether GAE datastore supports non-English characters as the id part of a key.

Comment: Yes, you can, but in this particular case you shouldn't because you could'nt modify IDs (usernames)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from the horse's mouth, the source code (the [key](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/key.py) class):

> - Kinds and string ids must not be empty and must be at most 500 bytes   long (after UTF-8 encoding, if given as Python unicode objects).

If UTF-8 is used you should be able to use any language you want. Also, from this [doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown):

> The next component is an ID (int64) or key name (str).

'str' as defined on the top of the page suggests non-ASCII chars are accepted.

p.s. Using usernames as unique IDs has some disadvantages; See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103433/why-use-an-auto-incrementing-primary-key-when-other-unique-fields-exist) (ignore the SQL aspect of it.)

Comment: great answer OmegaDirective, very indepth, thank you very much! :)